# Why the minimum of this multivariate polynomial is not a critical point?

Tags: systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

I have this multivariate polynomial function

$$\begin{align*} f(L,x,y,z) &= L^2 + (1 - L x)^2 + (1 - L y)^2 + (1 - L z)^2 \\
&+ (2 - L x y)^2 + (2 - L x z)^2 + (2 - L y z)^2 + (3 - L x y z)^2
\end{align*}$$

To compute its minimum an idea is to computes its critical points and then verify which of them minimizes $f$. This is a differentiable function, so all maxima and minima of $f$ are critical points, right?

Solving the equation $\nabla f(L,x,y,z) = (0,0,0,0)$ we can find its critical points. Supposing $L \neq 0$, we have the following polynomial system.
$$ \begin{cases}
  \begin{align*} X &+ Y + Z + 2 X Y + 2 X Z + 2 Y Z + 3 X Y Z \\
&-L(1 + X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + X^2 Y^2 + X^2 Z^2 + Y^2 Z^2 + X^2 Y^2 Z^2) = 0
\end{align*}\\
  -1 + Y - Y^2 + Z + 2 Y Z - Z^2 - Y^2 Z^2 = 0\\
  -1 + X - X^2 + Z + 2 X Z - Z^2 - X^2 Z^2 = 0\\
  -1 + X - X^2 + Y + 2 X Y - Y^2 - X^2 Y^2 = 0\\
 \end{cases}$$

I tried to solve this system using *Mathematica* and *PHCPack*. Both programs solved the system without a problem, but both missed the actually minimum. I had to use a minimizer routine in *Mathematica* to get the minimum $(L,x,y,z) = \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{9}, \frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{4}, \frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{4}, \frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{4} \right)$. This point minimizes $f$ but is not a solution of the system
above.

My question is, why this minimum is not a critical point? How is that possible?

Comment: I changed the math formatting somewhat to avoid the equations running off the margin, and to group terms of like form/degree together better.  Please review the edit to see if I unintentionally altered your meaning.

Comment: To the equation $$\nabla _{\{x,y,z,L\}}\left(L^2+(3-L x y z)^2+(2-L x y)^2+(2-L x z)^2+(1-L x)^2+(2-L y z)^2+(1-L y)^2+(1-L z)^2\right)=\vec O$$ *Mathematica* gave me exactly your solution $$\left\{x\to \frac{1}{4} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right),y\to \frac{1}{4} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right),z\to \frac{1}{4} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right),L\to \frac{1}{9} \left(1+\sqrt{17}\right)\right\}$$ which gives the local minimum $$\frac{1}{6} \left(73-17 \sqrt{17}\right)\approx 0.4845 $$

Comment: The system looks like this
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 -3 z y-2 y-2 z+L \left(x z^2 y^2+x y^2+x z^2+x\right)-1=0 \\
 -3 z x-2 x-2 z+L \left(y z^2 x^2+y x^2+y z^2+y\right)-1=0 \\
 -3 y x-2 x-2 y+L \left(y^2 z x^2+z x^2+y^2 z+z\right)-1=0 \\
 -2 y x-3 y z x-2 z x-x-y-2 y z-z+L \left(y^2 x^2+y^2 z^2 x^2+z^2 x^2+x^2+y^2+y^2 z^2+z^2+1\right)=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: @Raffaele:  Perhaps you should post this as an Answer.  As a Comment it causes margins to overrun (the issue I fixed by editing the Question).

Comment: But I don't know how to solve that system! I used Mathematica to get the solutions.. better let as a comment :)

Comment: @Raffaele which command did you use in Mathematica? I tried Solve[] and it didn't work for me... Can you detect what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: The gradient is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Reduce[Grad[L^2+(1-L x)^2+(1-L y)^2+(2-L x y)^2+(1-L z)^2+(2-L x z)^2+(2-L y z)^2+
(3-L x y z)^2,{L,x,y,z}]=={0,0,0,0}&&L!=0,{L,x,y,z}]
```